# Golang Channels dealing with send != receive

Tags: go

Consider the toy example below. The code works perfectly but when you interchange the 2 lines marked as `replace`, there will be a deadlock. Is there a better way to deal with such a situation when you have different number of sends and receives?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    a := make(chan string)
    b := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
            go func(i int) {
                fmt.Println(<-a)
                b <- strconv.Itoa(i) + "b" // replace
                a <- strconv.Itoa(i) + "a" // replace
            }(i)
        }
    }()

    a <- "0"
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-b)
    }
}
```

EDIT: using a select statement, there's a chance that `a` gets picked up by the select and there's still no way to prevent a deadlock because the goroutines can't execute

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    a := make(chan string)
    b := make(chan string)
    c := make(chan bool)
    cancel := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
            go func(i int) {
                fmt.Println(<-a)
                b <- strconv.Itoa(i) + "b" // replace
                a <- strconv.Itoa(i) + "a" // replace
                c <- true
            }(i)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        <-c
        <-c
        cancel <- true
    }()

    a <- "0"

loop:
    for {
        select {
        case ain := <-a:
            fmt.Println("select", ain)
        case bin := <-b:
            fmt.Println("select", bin)
        case <-cancel:
            break loop
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use select:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    a := make(chan string)
    b := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
            go func(i int) {
                fmt.Println(<-a)
                b <- strconv.Itoa(i) + "b" // replace
                a <- strconv.Itoa(i) + "a" // replace
            }(i)
        }
    }()

    // regardless of which comes in first, this will handle it 
    select {
    case ain <- a:
        fmt.Println("sent a", ain)
    case bin <- b:
        fmt.Println("sent b", bin)
    case <- cancel:
        break
    }
}
```

That example will sit and block for an item sent on either a or b channels.

Optionally I usually set a cancel token or a timeout.

Your original code deadlocks on the switch because you sent on B, where you were only listening on A.  Golang requires you to be listening on the channel BEFORE you ever send to it. This is the pattern for multiple channels, not knowing which you are going to get first.

Comment: Where do you suggest I put this ... My example is just a simplification, `<-a` and `<-b` have to be where I put them in the code. Don't think I can change their locations

Comment: Updated with your code. You original code doesn't make sense as no actual program can be written like that.  You always want to block on the receiver of the channel, period. If you have more than one channel, you need a `select` to block on the first input of them.  If you have multiple inputs, wrap the select in a for loop.

Comment: Sounds like B is the "cancel" case in my example.  ;)

Comment: Sorry. You are going to have to update your code to exactly your use case as what I have posted resolves the current example code provided.

Comment: Now if you are sending multiple values on these channels, that's a different use case and pattern.  You may need to use a WaitGroup instead to keep track of how many you send on the channels between goroutines.  Again, update the example to your exact use case if you are sending multiples.  Also, you can  wrap the select case I provided in a for loop as well and break out when your B or cancel condition is met.

Comment: I guess it would be more suitable for code review ... I'll post the link if you'd like to take a look!

Comment: Cancel can be a simple Boolean channel  From within another goroutine, when ever you are all done, just send "true" on the cancel channel - and it will exit the routine.  You can build safe draining or other resourcesl cleanups with cancel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145649/discussion-between-eduncan911-and-tushar).

Comment: For the purposes of cancel channels, using a `chan struct{}` and _closing_ it when you should cancel is often a superior option.  A `struct{}` has 0 size, so it's cheaper than a bool (though they are both super cheap), and a close alerts _all_ listeners at once, instead of having to send a value over the channel for every listener.